# How do I enable SELinux when booting a ramdisk from a CD/DVD?

Tags: linux, selinux

I have a bootable DVD which boots the same Kernel as the Hard Drive (which uses SELinux). I have copied /etc/selinux and all kernel modules to my ramdisk, and have tried various combinations of `selinux=1` and `selinux 1` with `enforcing 1` and `enforcing 0`. as Kernel boot parameters. All files contained in the checkpolicy, libselinux, policycoreutils, selinux-policy and selinux-policy-targeted rpms have also been copied into the ramdisk tree.

After the system boots from the ramdisk, I check dmesg:

```
% dmesg | grep -i selinux
Kernel command line: initrd=idrd.img ramdisk_size=110476 selinux=1
SELinux: Initializing.
SELinux: Starting in permissive mode
selinux_register_security: Registering secondary module capability
SElinux: Registering netfilter hooks
```

But SELinux isn't running:

```
% /usr/sbin/getenforce
Disabled
% /usr/sbin/setenforce 1
/usr/sbin/setenforce: SELinux is disabled
```

Neither `/var/log/messages` nor `/proc/kmsg` hold clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's not immediately obvious is that SELINUX requires selinuxfs to be mounted. When mounted, selinuxfs appears in /proc/mounts but *not* in the output of the mount command.

Mounting selinuxfs in my initrd did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure.  What distro, out of curiosity?  Perhaps `enforcing=1` will do the trick. [Dan Walsh is pretty knowledgeable on this](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/10972.html), I think he does the policy for SELinux @ Fedora.  I also base it off the [Fedora Docs wiki page](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/Config).

Comment: This is for RHEL5.4, I already saw the Dan Walsh article. I've tried adding enforcing=0. My Boot CD mounts the hard drive and changes files, and needs to do things without interference from SELinux. Relabeling everything is not an option for this, so I was hoping to run the restorecond daemon to clean things up. There are too many changes for running restorecon on individual files to practical. The restorecond daemon will not run unless SELinux is enabled, so I need to run it in permissive mode.

Comment: @JeffG Sorry I could not be of more help, I was just taking a shot in the dark there.